# LGPL3 code in GPL3 project

Tags: gpl, gpl-3, lgpl

It seems like this should be obvious, but I'm not finding an answer. LGPL is a subset of GPL, IIRC, so can I use LGPL code in a GPL project?

Comment: To be more specific, I'm hoping to use code from the wimlib project (LGPL3) in the samba project (GPL3). Rewriting the code in question would be significant.

Comment: From the [GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility): "LGPLv3 is GPLv3 plus extra permissions that you can ignore in this case."

Comment: Thanks. That chart is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LGPL-3.0 is implemented as the GPL-3.0 plus additional permissions under Section 7 of the GPL-3.0. “When you convey a copy of a covered work, you may at your option remove any additional permissions from that copy, or from any part of it.” I.e. you can ignore these extra permissions if you want to.

So you are free to use LGPL-3.0 code as if it were GPL-3.0 licensed (because it is).

As pointed out by Bart van Ingen Schenau in the comments, this is also explained in the [GPL license family compatibility chart](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility) in the GPL FAQ.